# Llamar una funcion PHP desde Vue

Tags: php, vue.js, pdo

Se puede llamar una función PHP desde Vue.js directamente?

mi problema es el siguiente, (de más está decir que estoy iniciando con VUE):

En una tabla se muestran los datos indicados,
en la columna {{data.actividad}} me devuelve un id que relaciona otra tabla donde está el nombre al que pertenece ese identificador.

```
<tr v-for="(data,index) in buscarHorario" v-show="(pag - 1) * elementosPorPagina <= index  && pag * elementosPorPagina > index">
       <td>{{data.dia}}</td>
       <td>{{data.nombre_dia}}</td>
       <td>{{data.hora}}</td>
       <td>{{data.sala}}</td>
       <td><?php echo queactividad('{{data.actividad}}');?></td>
 </tr>
```

Resultado:
1 | Lunes | 16:00 | Sala 1 | 5

Esperado :
1 | Lunes | 16:00 | Sala 1 | **Musculación**

Intenté hacer una función PHP tal como lo muestro, pero no me retorna el nombre requerido, pero si me devuelve el id si lo retorno a través de la función.

```
<?php
    function queactividad($ide){
          $conexion = Conectar::conexion(); 
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM actividades WHERE id = :id ";
          $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
          $statement->bindValue(':id', $ide);
          $statement->execute();
          $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $row['nombre'] ??= $ide;
         //return $ide;
         //return $row['nombre'];
     }
?>
```

Se puede implementar esto con VUE o de que manera relativamente entendible se puede realizar ?
Espero haber sido bastante explícito.
Soy novato iniciando en VueJS!

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Php y Vue (javascript) se ejecutan en lugares y momentos diferentes, por lo que no se podría hacer así como lo planteas. Como alternativa, algo bastante común es hacer una API en Php y consumirla con Javascript

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera de hacer lo que quieres es delegar el envió de datos con PHP y mostrar los resultados con vue.

Crea una API con PHP y haz una llamada a esa API con vue usando fetch o axios.